# How to check shape length before running code in Python/ArcPy?

Tags: python, arcpy

I am using a code to convert a polygon into evenly spaced parallel lines

```
for point in range(0,numPoints+1):
        shortPoint1 = currentLines[firstLong].positionAlongLine(lineSpaceNum*point)
        shortPoint2 = currentLines[firstLong + 2].positionAlongLine(currentLines[firstLong + 2].length - (lineSpaceNum*point))
        parallel = arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([shortPoint1.centroid,shortPoint2.centroid]), SR)
```

but the problem is that sometimes the first line it will produce has a shape_length of 0 which causes other scripts to break. If the object is square it will have a shape_length > 0 but if it is an unusual polygon it wont.

Comment: How about running Repair geometry on your lines after they are constructed? That should remove features with no length, but you'll have to try it for this specific case.

Comment: Alternatively add an 'if' statement to check line length.

Comment: Have you considered using the Fishnet tool to create parallel lines?

Comment: @Martin I think repair geometry will be the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

I simply used arcpy.RepairGeometry_management (outParallel) to remove any 0 length lines.